# Python 3: Slice a rhyme

Tags: python-3.x, computer-science

Assign sub_lyric with 'cow' by slicing rhyme_lyric from start_index to end_index. Sample output from the given program:

cow

```
start_index = 4
end_index = 7
rhyme_lyric = 'The cow jumped over the moon.'
sub_lyric = rhyme_lyric''' Your solution goes here '''
print(sub_lyric)
```

Comment: It's not clear what you'd like help with.  SO is not for providing OP with complete solutions.  It is intended to help you understand difficulties you've encountered.

Answer (score 0):

This is what your looking for :

```
start_index = 4
end_index = 7
rhyme_lyric = 'The cow jumped over the moon.'
sub_lyric = rhyme_lyric [start_index: end_index]
print(sub_lyric)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what you need

```
start_index = 4
end_index = 7
rhyme_lyric = 'The cow jumped over the moon.'
sub_lyric = rhyme_lyric[start_index : end_index]
print(sub_lyric)
```

Strings in python are considered as lists and arrays, and its ith character can be accessed as `string[i]`. Further, `rhyme_lyric` contained the word cow, and its slicing was done to extract 'cow'. You can read more about slicing at https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/interesting-facts-about-strings-in-python-set-2/

Answer (score 0):

I have been checking all the solutions given from here and performed simple analysis.
The solution that worked for me is by using following code line:

`sub_lyric = rhyme_lyric[start_index:end_index]`

Answer (score -1):

```
start_index = int(input())
end_index = int(input())
rhyme_lyric = 'The cow jumped over the moon.'
sub_lyric = rhyme_lyric[start_index:end_index]
print(sub_lyric)
```